# Modifying different lists by css

Tags: html, css

My HTML file is:

```
asdfasdf
<ul>
    <li id="differentstyle">Car</li>
    <li>Car1</li>
    <li>Travel</li>
</ul>
```

and my CSS style is:

```
#differentstyle ul li {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

but this style is not modifying the "car" (the first one). Am I doing anything wrong? Is this suppose to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not style anything, because `#differentstyle ul li` selects a `<li/>` inside a  `<ul/>` inside `#differentstyle`, but there is no  `<ul/>` inside your `#differentstyle`. Use

```
ul li {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

instead if you want to style all `<li/>` elements. Or use

```
#differentstyle {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

if you just want to style the first `<li/>`. Or, if it's really just the first you want to style differently and you just want the styles to apply to a specific list, change your html to

```
<ul id="yourClass">
    <li>Car</li>
    <li>Car1</li>
    <li>Travel</li>
</ul>
```

And use this css:

```
#yourClass > li {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#yourClass > li:first-child {
    padding-bottom: 100px; /* different style for the first item */
}
```

Comment: Hey This below line is working perfectly
ul li {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

So Why you add extra css lines??? Can you remove extra all lines??

You want check it : http://jsbin.com/oqeteh/10/edit

Answer (score 1):

`#differentstyle ul li` : means, the `li` inside the `ul` inside `#differentstyle`, and there's no `li` inside a `ul` inside `#differentstyle`.

So simply use:

```
#differentstyle {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Fore More Info: [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your selector `#differentstyle ul li {` means "match a li which is a descendant of a ul which is a descendant of an element with the id 'differentstyle'". If you want to target that first li, simply use `#differentstyle { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a height problem .  and some code issues  for use `margin-bottom: 50px;` instead of `padding-bottom`

so remove your all code .Just try to add below code

```
<ul>
    <li id="differentstyle">Car</li>
    <li>Car1</li>
    <li>Travel</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul 
{
    height:160px;//Its not a important 
}

ul li 
{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Please see this [output design](http://jsbin.com/oqeteh/6/edit)

Comment: Why do you set a fixed height for the `<ul/>`?

Comment: if  the ul height is less than 50% ,hot to get padding-bottom in thus ul . So i set hright in ul tag . But its not a important .

Comment: Sorry for my above poor typing. 
If the UL tag height is less than 50px ,The LI tag can't to get padding-bottom :50px . So i set height in UL tag . But its does not a matter !

Comment: It's not the typing, I do not understand your logic. For example 50% of what? But as I said: nevermind.

Comment: Hey Its not a logic . What you mean ?? I said the  UL tag  total height is less than 50px .But both of all li tag padding_bottom is 50px . So how can achieve this?? total Ul tag height size and one li tag padding-bottom size is same .So the li tag can't get  padding_bottom  50px .that's all

Comment: Yeah, now you changed from `50%` to `50px`. I see what you mean. But that does not answer my initial question. Giving the `<ul/>` a height that surely is bigger than it's `<li/>` elements (and you can never be sure, but let's say for the monent) is the same as leaving the `height` alone (=`auto`). But maybe I don't see something you see, possible.